# PrimeFaces - can't rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a little problem with the rendered attribute. I want to use it for login, if someone connects for the first time on my website, he can log in, but when he's logged, he can't see the form. But when the page is loaded, I can't hide the form...

Maybe it would be easier with my code.

**HTML**

```
              <h:panelGroup id="sidebar" layout="block">
                <h:panelGroup id="sbox1" layout="block">
                    <h:panelGroup class="title" layout="block">
                        <h2> Espace Membre </h2>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <ul class="style2">
                            <h:form rendered="#{!membreCtrl.estConnecte}">
                                Connection : <h:outputText value="#{membreCtrl.estConnecte}"></h:outputText>
                                Login : <h:inputText id="login" value="#{membreCtrl.login}" /> <br/>
                                Password : <h:inputSecret id="mdp" value="#{membreCtrl.mdp}" /> <br/>
                                <h:commandButton action="#{membreCtrl.identifier()}" value="Se connecter" />
                            </h:form>
                    </ul>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

**Bean**

```
 public String identifier() {
    membreConnecte = membreEJB.connecter(login, mdp);
    if (membreConnecte == null) {
        return "FAILURE";
    }
    estConnecte = true;
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

If I put the right login/password, I get on the index page, but then I would like to hide the `<h:form ..`that I wrote.
But it doesn't work. When I print the result in the Bean, my boolean "estConnecte" is true,  but not when I write it on the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the form after the button's click?

Put a p:outputPanel inside the form, if you are using Primefaces, and then update the form:

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{!membreCtrl.estConnecte}">
       Connection : <h:outputText value="#{membreCtrl.estConnecte}"></h:outputText>
       Login : <h:inputText id="login" value="#{membreCtrl.login}" /> <br/>
       Password : <h:inputSecret id="mdp" value="#{membreCtrl.mdp}" /> <br/>
       <p:commandButton action="#{membreCtrl.identifier()}" value="Se connecter" update="@form"/>
    <p:outputPanel/>
 </h:form>
```